# Heroku build fails with Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

We run a Rails 6.x app with webpacker gem compiling the client-side assets. Up until recently the build was working fine. But today the build is failing with the following error.

```
SEGV received in SEGV handler
       /tmp/build_b2510ec8/bin/rake: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000480
       ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]
       
       Aborted
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

I can precompile assets locally on my MacBook with no problems. This error is extremely opaque so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it. Can anyone tell me what this means and/or how to fix it?

Comment: There isn't really that much more we can help you with - you need to see if you can dig any more information [out the logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging). A segfault is caused by a program trying to access memory that is not allocated to it, and it doesn't really tell you anything about what caused it or how to rectify the problem.

Comment: "A segfault is caused by a program trying to access memory that is not allocated to it"  This is a helpful clue!

Comment: Yeah, but not really. Segfaults are kind of rare in Ruby and other interpreted languages since they don't allow direct memory allocation. When they do happen its typically due to errors in the underlying libraries which are written in C.